# Настройка кода в плагине Dataview в Obsidian для подсчёта суммы данных в заданном временном интервале

Tags: sql

Настройка кода в плагине Dataview в Obsidian для подсчёта суммы данных в заданном временном интервале

Здраствуйте!
У меня возник вопрос по использованию плагина Dataview в Obsidian. Мне нужно настроить код для подсчёта суммы данных в определенном временном интервале, например, между 11 августа 2023 года и 11 октября 2023 года. Как это можно реализовать?

Вот основной код где нужно изменить или добавить:

```
TABLE WITHOUT ID  
    sum(number(rows.budget_g)) + " t" AS "Summa"
FROM #sss1  
GROUP BY true
```

Это отделньные файлы:

```
---
date: 2023-02-02T16:58:13+06:00
budget_g: 25000
tags:
  - sss1
updated: 2024-01-03T17:24:51+06:00
---
```

```
---
date: 2023-04-02T16:58:35+06:00
budget_g: 23000
tags:
  - sss1
updated: 2024-01-03T17:24:47+06:00
---
```

```
---
date: 2023-09-11T22:53:27+06:00
budget_g: 27000
tags:
  - sss1
updated: 2024-01-03T17:24:49+06:00
---
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]